# Problemas trigger MERGE

Tags: sql-server

Hola buen dia tengo el siguiente trigger el cual me genera un error:

```
Mensaje 515, nivel 16, estado 2, procedimiento TEST, línea 31 [línea de inicio de lote 0]
No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'C3', tabla 'DBABA.dbo.KDIHCS'. La columna no admite valores NULL. Error de UPDATE.
Se terminó la instrucción.
```

y mi codigo de trigger es el siguiente :

```
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TEST]    Script Date: 07/01/2019 03:33:15 p. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TEST]
ON [dbo].[KDICLA] FOR INSERT,UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SUC AS CHAR(7)
    DECLARE @PROD AS CHAR(18)
    DECLARE @CLAS AS CHAR(2)
    DECLARE @FECHA AS DATETIME
    DECLARE @USUARIO AS CHAR (23)
    DECLARE @VENTAS AS DECIMAL(15,2)
    DECLARE @HORA AS CHAR(5)

    SET @SUC= (SELECT C1 FROM INSERTED)
    SET @PROD = (SELECT C2 FROM INSERTED)
    SET @CLAS = (SELECT C3 FROM INSERTED)
    SET @FECHA = (SELECT C4 FROM INSERTED)
    SET @USUARIO= (SELECT C5 FROM INSERTED)
    SET @VENTAS= (SELECT C6 FROM INSERTED)
    SET @HORA= (SELECT C7 FROM INSERTED)

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    MERGE KDIHCS AS TARGET
    USING(SELECT @SUC, @PROD, @FECHA, @CLAS, @VENTAS, @HORA, @USUARIO ) AS SOURCE(C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7)
    ON (TARGET.C1 = SOURCE.C1 AND TARGET.C2 = SOURCE.C2 AND TARGET.C3 = SOURCE.C3)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
                   C4 = SOURCE.C4,
                   C5=SOURCE.C5,
                   C6=SOURCE.C6,
                   C7=SOURCE.C7
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7)
        VALUES (SOURCE.C1, SOURCE.C2, SOURCE.C3, SOURCE.C4, SOURCE.C5, SOURCE.C6, SOURCE.C7);
END
```

no se en que parte estoy mal por lo que yo veo en los set con las variables no me trae valor pero no se es que puedo estar mal

Comment: La columna `C3`  de la tabla `DBABA.dbo.KDIHCS` no acepta `NULL`, y es eso lo que le estarías pasando, imagino yo, desde `@CLAS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo creo que el error lo tienes cuando intenta añadir:

```
INSERT (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7)
VALUES (SOURCE.C1, SOURCE.C2, SOURCE.C3, SOURCE.C4, SOURCE.C5, SOURCE.C6, SOURCE.C7);
```

Porque SOURCE.C3 debe ser NULO en algún caso y como no hace el MATCH para hacer el UPDATE intenta hacer el INSERT y falla por NULL.
"No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'C3', tabla 'DBABA.dbo.KDIHCS'"
Como C3 parece ser parte de la clave deberías forzar a que no sea nulo también en SOURCE.

Comment: gracias de hecho si tenia problemas en el insert nada mas ahi estaba el error